# Unable to get data returned from PHP via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get data returned from a function in a PHP file via AJAX (using Chrome)

The JS:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.site.co.uk/api/file.php',
            data: data, 
            dataType: 'json', 
            type: 'POST', 
            contentType: 'application/json',
            async: false,
            success: function (jsonData){
                console.log("SUCCESS");
                var responseText = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData.responseText);
                console.log(responseText);
            },
            error: function (jsonData){
                console.log("ERROR");
                var responseText = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData.responseText);
                console.log(responseText);
            }
        });
```

Relevant part of the PHP:

```
public function post_method()
{
    $data['error_message'] = "Error message text";
    return json_encode($data);
}
```

In the console I'm getting:

```
POST http://www.site.co.uk/api/file.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
ERROR
Object {status: "{", message: "{"}
```

In the PHP, if I replace

```
return json_encode($data);
```

with

```
return $data;
```

the console shows

```
SUCCESS
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u jquery.js:3
```

Not sure why I can't get 'error_message', and not sure why using 'json_encode' appears to produce a 500 error.

@Johannes Reuter -  It's slightly complicated but I'm calling post_method() like this:

```
public function route_method()
{
   switch($this->resource['request_method'])
    {
        case 'POST':
            return $this->post_method();
            break;
        default:
            return FALSE;
            break;                
    }

}
```

This is part of some api framework code that I didn't write. '$this->resource' is essentially being passed into the class constructor. The same method is used successfully in other PHP files.

@Rory McCrossan - how should I define it? I thought it was OK just to create it as an array.

Comment: Can you show where you define `$data` in your PHP code and what it contains. The second error is because you've told jQuery to deserialise a JSON response, yet the response was not JSON.

Comment: Could you add the code that is calling post_method()?

Comment: Use `die()` instead of return - `die(json_encode($data));` or `echo` and `die` combo.

Comment: Check if you are `echo` your data in your `php` file. You should `echo` it and not `return` it.

Comment: What data are you passing using data is it `form.serialize()` or else

Comment: Edited above to answer some of these questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inform `dataType` as json in the request, just dont need use `jQuery.parseJSON` function because it's **json**.

Answer (score 0):

you will try.

```
echo json_encode($data);exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `echo json_encode($data);die;` instead of `return json_encode($data);`